# Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed

Tags: boot, pi-3, boot-issues, ubuntu

Occasionally my Pi3 will crash during boot and hang on the error message:

```
Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed
```

Manually power cycling it sometimes fixes this, but sometimes the error immediately re-occurs. What's causing this?

It seems to occur more often if I try to SSH into my Pi while it's booting.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Edit: I'm also occasionally seeing the error:

```
Unable to handle kernel null point at virtual address
```

during boot, which also hangs.

Would this be caused by a corrupt or defective SD card? I'm using an 8GB Kingston, which is [reported to work](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards#Working_.2F_Non-working_SD_cards).

Comment: Well, you're not alone. I just upgraded from jessie to stretch, and see the same on at least one π3. I have a booting issue with an original like model b as well (blank screen). So there may be something. I'm using raspbian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by an incorrectly compiled kernel for the ARM platform. The images I was using weren't properly designed for the Pi. Unfortunately, Canonical doesn't offer any official ARM images, and most of the unofficial ones are poorly built.

However, from [this site](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/) I found [this](http://phillw.net/isos/pi2/ubuntu-minimal-16.04-server-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz) Ubuntu 16.04 image works perfectly with the Pi3.